# How to change the below "ForEach loop" into simple IList<Record> or any other collection?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, performance, foreach

1. Foreach loop in my below code is taking more time for 50,00,000 Records.
2. Instead I need to change and assign it to a simple List or Ienumerable collection to find Distinct collection.

My question is how to convert the below ForEach loop into a `List<Records>` or any other collection (without using loop). I have added my coding structure. Please help me resolve. //Please refer the comments in CODE.

```
Class MainFilter
{

  Private Void GetRecords()
  {
    List<object> choices = new List<Object>();

    // Instead of the below line can I get the FilterItems implicitly converted.
    // I need a collection without ForeachLoop...something like the below.
    // List<Record> recordsCollection = table.FilterItems; Please help.
    // Foreach loop is taking more time I need this to be converted to 
    // simple collection using IList or Enumerable

    foreach (Record rec in table.FilterItems)
    {
      Choices.Add(rec.GetValue());
    }

  }

}

Public Class SecondTable: IContainerElement, IDisposable
{

  public ThirdFilterItems FilterItems
  {
    get
    {
      _filteredRecords = new ThirdFilterItems(this);
    }
  }

}

public class ThirdFilterItems: FourthFilterItems
{

  internal ThirdFilterItems(SecondTable table) : base(table)
  {
  }

}

public class FourthFilterItems: IList, IDisposable
{

  public Record this[int index]
  {
    get
    {
      return record;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: At some point, a loop is always involved.  50 million records?  Maybe the database should handle that.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks Is there any chance to assign it a collection instead of using Foreach loop.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're initial problem is. Is it taking to long? You can trying running the conversion on multiple threads, paralleling it.

Comment: @LarsTech yes its taking more time.. its a collection of "Record"... but i cannot able to case it to a List or IEnumerable collection...

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you a collection of "choices" without yet iterating over the collection.

```
table.FilterItems.Select(x => x.GetValue())
```

Is that what you're looking for? It's not a list. If you need to convert it to a list then you will have to iterate over the collection to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, using Linq:

```
List<Record> recordsCollection = table.FilterItems
                                      .Select(r => r.GetValue())
                                      .ToList();
```

But don't expect it to be faster... internally, it still does the same thing as your original code. There's no way to solve this problem without a loop, or the moral equivalent of a loop.

Comment: Thanks.. but Select method is not available in it.

Comment: @Arun Do you have: `using System.Linq;` as the top of your code?

Comment: @Arun, what is the type of FilterItems?

Comment: FilterItems should be IEnumerable<T>